# Form 8936 for 2018- Qualified Plug-in Electric Drive Motor Vehicle Credit

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs, car

I have been looking for form 8936 for 2018 in order to file my tax returns but have been able to find only the one for 2017 as below.

https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-8936

Is there an update which is still needed on the website or can I just use the 2017 one in case the reason for no update is that the only change required was the year number?

Comment: As of January 21, 2019, the 2018 Form 8936 has not been released yet. Some other 2018 forms have also not been released; they are only partly done with 2018 tax forms and they release more every day. Note that the tax filing season does not start until January 28.

Comment: Update: the 2018 Form 8936 form and instructions are now online.